# C# AutoMapper does not copy Collections

Tags: c#, list, automapper

What's the mistake in the following code, when I try to copy on List to an other?
The count of `list` is always 0.

```
using (WeldingEntities db = new WeldingEntities())
{
    var query = db.Users.Select(x => x).ToList();
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<List<User>, List<SimpleUser>>());
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var list = mapper.Map<List<SimpleUser>>(query);
        return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify the collection type in your map definition. You just need to specify the individual type and automapper can figure out collection mapping on its own.

`var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<User, SimpleUser>());`

See [docs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Lists-and-arrays) for more info on the collection types that are supported.